# Linq to Sql result in combobox async

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I'm developing a winform application and would make a request in the database and populate my combobox asynchronously but am having problem of access control because they come from another thread, here's the code.

```
   this.backWorker.DoWork + = delegate
             {
                 comboBoxUsers.DataSource = repositoryUser.SelectAll();
                 comboBoxUsers.ValueMember = "UserId";
                 comboBoxUsers.DisplayMember = "Name";
             };

             backWorker.RunWorkerAsync ();
```

I am studying about envoke but I'm having trouble getting to implement this,
I needed to do was leave the DoWork event visible progress bar and select to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only query your repository on the BackgroundWorker and return the results through the ProgressChangedEvenHandler to the UI

```
   //Set the ComboBox Properties on the Form, not in the worker.
   comboBoxUsers.ValueMember = "UserId";
   comboBoxUsers.DisplayMember = "Name";

   BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
   worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
   worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Worker_ProgressChanged);

   private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
        BackgrounderWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

        //Query the database
        //Instantiate a custom-class to contain the results
        IList<Users> users = userRepository.SelectAll();
        QueryResults results = new QueryResults(users);
        worker.ReportProgress(0, results);
   }

   //Back In the UI Layer
   private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       var result = (QueryResult)e.UserState;
       comboBoxUsers.DataSource = result.Users;
   }
```

Comment: Also, if the ComboBox's ValueMember and DisplayMember are never going to change you can set those in the form's constructor or the associated designer.cs file itself.  The only thing you truly care about is returning the query results to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

your delegate should be written like this:

```
this.backWorker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
  //...
}
```

for details on how to access UI controls of the UI Thread from another thread see here:

[Access windows control from Backgroundworker DoWork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463206/access-windows-control-from-backgroundworker-dowork)

there is a clear answer at that link, here a snippet:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {

  // This code executes on the GUI thread.

}));
```

Comment: do not quite understand, how do I access the combobox?