# Datatable not displaying information after SQL query fill in backgroundworker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am filling a `DataTable` with the data from a SQL query. As it can be quite slow, I am running the query and doing some computations on the `DataTable` using `BackgroundWorker`. I know the background thread has run because in `RunWorkerCompleted` I have set a `MessageBox` to display a message. Once complete, however, there is no data displayed in the `DataTable`.

I know this code works, because when I run directly from the button click and not using `BackgroundWorker`, I see all the expected data in the `DataTable`.  The issue is likely something with how the UI updates and the `BackgroundWorker`, as I know you can't update the UI directly from another thread, but I honestly don't know. My code is below.

```
    DataTable tab1table = new DataTable();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instantiatesearch1Thread();
    }

    private void Instantiatesearch1Thread()
    {
        search1Thread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        search1Thread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        search1Thread.ProgressChanged += search1Thread_ProgressChanged;
        search1Thread.DoWork += search1Thread_Dowrk;
        search1Thread.RunWorkerCompleted += search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

        private void sbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        search1Thread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    void search1Thread_Dowrk(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int percentprogress = 0;
        percentprogress++;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // Search1 button event handler
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {

            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(comboBox1SQL, conn))
            {
                if (comboBox1.Text.Contains("ID"))
                {
                    long para = long.Parse(search1.Text);
                    cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@combo1Par",
                        Value = para,
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt
                    });
                }

                else if (comboBox1.Text.Contains("Other Thing") || comboBox1.Text.Contains("Other Stuff"))
                {
                    string para = search1.Text;
                    cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@combo1Par",
                        Value = "%" + para + "%",
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                    });
                }
                // Clear datatable if it contains any information and then fill it
                // tab1datatable is a DataGridView
                if (tab1table != null)
                    tab1table.Clear();
                cmd.Fill(tab1table);
                tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;

            // A bunch of long calculations 
            }
        }
    }

    void search1Thread_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        search1Progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("All Done!");
    }
```

Comment: what is `tab1datatable` a `DataGridView` or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is a `DataGridView`.

Comment: Then you can call either `tab1datatable.Update()` or `tab1datatable.Refresh()` after you have updated the `DataSource`.

Comment: @vikscool How do I update the `DataSource`? In `search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted`, when I use `tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;` and then use `tab1datatable.Update()` I get a single, blank cell displayed.

Answer (score 2):

For the `BackgroundWorker` you have to change your process a bit:

Instead of updating the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` in the `search1Thread_Dowrk` of `BackgroundWorker` just update the `DataTable` in it and then on your `search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted` call the DataSource updation process.

Change you code from this:

```
void search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("All Done!");
}
```

To:

```
void search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;
    tab1datatable.Refresh(); 
    MessageBox.Show("All Done!");
}
```

Comment: Should I delete the `tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;` from the `search1Thread_Dowrk` function as well? Does that create a redundancy?

Comment: It still doesn't work, for some reason. To make sure I wasn't doing anything wrong, I put the code directly into the search1 event handler and it gave me the desired results. Do you know what could be messing up?

Comment: probably you should check whether the `tab1table` is getting updated in the `DoWork` event.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it is not going in to the `if comboBox1.Text.Contains()` statements. And I am not sure why, to be honest.

Comment: Does it contain the text you are matching for?

Comment: It does. In fact it works when I copy the code out of the `BackgroundWorker` and put it directly into the button event handler. So for some reason, the `Combo`Box` contents are not being passed across the threads.

Comment: well the `BackgroundWorker` cannot access your form controls as they are on the `separate` thread more about this can be found on [Access windows control from Backgroundworker DoWork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463676/2417602).